# PHP Loop 1 to 10

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I need to make a loop in php that does 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 .... + 10 = 55 but icant get it to work. I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
            $sul = $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i;
            echo "$i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i + $i = $sul<br>";

        };

    ?>
</body>
```

Hope you can help me thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: `echo 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10;`  ;)

Comment: I need to do it into a loop its for school

Comment: @user7147407 you should try reading **[the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)** which provides you with enough examples.

Comment: Refer documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @user7147407, If you need the answer like `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55` Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @user7147407, the accepted answer doesn't print your desired output. Kindly check my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Updated if you want that kind of structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}
echo $sum;    
?>
```

You are incorrect using loop.

**Explanation**

I think it will be easier to understand with following table:

```
_____________________
|JUMP | $i   | $sum  |
|1    | 1    | 1     |
|2    | 2    | 3     |
|3    | 3    | 6     |
|4    | 4    | 10    |
|5    | 5    | 15    |
|6    | 6    | 21    |
|7    | 7    | 28    |
|8    | 8    | 36    |
|9    | 9    | 45    |
|10   | 10   | 55    |
```

More about `for` you can read in [PHP: for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

**Update**

If you want your structure it can be as follows:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$str = '';
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + $i;
    $str .= $i == 10 ? $i." = " : $i." + ";
}
echo $str.$sum;
?>
```

And it will output `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55`

Answer (score 7):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$range = range(1, 10);
$sum = array_sum($range);

echo implode(' + ', $range) . ' = ' . $sum;
```

range() - http://php.net/range

array_sum() - http://php.net/array_sum

implode() - http://php.net/implode

Answer (score 3):

Just make a for loop from starting 1 to 10, like given below. You need to initialize the counter as 0 and while the loop executes you need to collect / sum them to the counter and finally outside the loop print/ echo the counter.

```
$count = 0;
$string = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    $count += $i;

    $string .= ($i == 10) ? $i : $i." + ";
}
echo $string." = ".$count; // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
```

This is a very simple and straight forward way, you can do this using some array functions which is built-in in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hardcode it, you can do this

```
<?php
$answer = 0;    
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
         $answer = $i + $answer;
         if ($i == 10) {
           echo $i." = ".$answer;
         }
         else {
           echo $i." + ";
         }       
    };
?>
```

Output is:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: answer in

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, you downvoted my answer? Of course you have to initialize $answer = 0 before the loop.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, you should have realize that you should initialize the variable. SO is not an assignment-making website.

Comment: You should stated that when answering that the user needs to initialize answer, I know that I did not even run your code, but I knew there's a notice. You must remember when we answering we are also educating other people that might have the same problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $n = 10;
        $items = range(1, $n);
        $sum = array_sum($items);
        echo implode('+', $items) . ' = ' . $sum;
    ?>
</body>
```

This way is shorter.
You generate the array from 1 to $n(10);

Then you calculate the sum of the items.

And then join each element with '+' and add the sum.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
$sum = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if($i == 10){
        echo $i;
    } else {
        echo $i." + ";
    }
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}
echo " = ".$sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop actually repeats a block of code n times, you syntax is right buy your semantic is wrong: initializes a counter in 0 and add i to the counter in each step as the other people say. Also, if is not compulsory to use a for, remember that the sum of first n natural numbers is n(n+1)/2, so no loop is actually needed